# Unable to access public type members in another assembly. I have two assemblies, I want to access public members from one assembly in another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

```
using System;

namespace AssemblyOne
{

    public class AssemblyOneClassOne
    {
        protected internal int ID = 101;
        public int id = 102;
        public void Print() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Abdullah is a handsome hunk!");
        }
    }
    public class AssemblyOneClassTwo 
    {
        public void SampleMethod() 
        {
            AssemblyOneClassOne a1 = new AssemblyOneClassOne();
            Console.WriteLine(a1.ID);
        }
    }
    public class A
    { 
        public static void Main()
        {
            AssemblyOneClassTwo a2 = new AssemblyOneClassTwo();
            a2.SampleMethod();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using AssemblyOne;

namespace AssemblyTwo

{

    public class AssemblyTwoClassOne
    { 
        AssemblyOneClassOne instance = new AssemblyOneClassOne();
        instance.Print();//Over here I am getting compile time error, 'instance' does not exist in the current context, 'instance.Print' does not exist in the current context
    }
}
```

As far as I know, public types can be accessed in anywhere in the same assembly as well as in another assembly

Comment: You have the `instance.Print();` just in the root of the `AssemblyTwoClassOne` class. That should be inside of something like a method or constructor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, public types can be accessed from another assembly but your method `Print()` should be called inside a method of class `AssemblyTwoClassOne`.

Something like this -

```
namespace AssemblyTwo
{
    public class AssemblyTwoClassOne
    {
        AssemblyOneClassOne instance = new();
        public void Method() => instance.Print();
    }
}
```